# Can a function have the range of a set of functions

Tags: functions

Is there anything wrong with a function that maps elements of its domain to functions?

Example. Take the following two functions `f1` and `f2` (specified by listing the mappings of each). Each of `f1` and `f2` maps some natural numbers to alphabet letters:

```
f1 = {1 → a, 2 → b}
f2 = {1 → c, 2 → d}
```

And the function `f` which maps some natural numbers to functions (`f1` and `f2`):

```
f = {1 → f1, 2 → f2}
```

Comment: Well, why should there be anything wrong with this? The codomain/range is simply a set of functions now, and a set of functions is fundamentally no different from a set of alphabet letters or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely fine. One place where this is common is to take any function that takes two arguments, and only feed it one of its arguments.

Take the two-argument function known as "add", feed it $5$, and you now have the function "add $5$". Take a dot product on vectors of some fixed size, and reinterpret into a function that takes a single vector as input and yields a function that takes a single vector as input and yields a scalar back. What you have is the (matrix) transpose. There are plenty of other examples out there.

Lambda calculus (and programming languages inspired by it, like Haskell) doesn't even really have multi-input functions, and instead stimulate them by creating functions that yield functions, in a sort of reversal of the above.

Slightly more formally, by definition a function is an assignment that takes each element of the domain to exactly one element of the codomain. That's all we require of functions. If the codomain of your function happens to be a set of functions, then that's what you get when you apply your function.

Comment: Great example. And if the poster wants to read more about this in Haskell, the term to search for  is "currying".